Next.jsとRails APIモードで開発しているアプリにGoogle認証を導入したい
現状
現在Next.js 14とRails　7 APIモードでアプリ開発しています。開発中のリポジトリ
すでに通常のメールアドレス、パスワードでのユーザ新規作成・ログインの実装が済んでいます。
dockerを使ってコンテナを立てて開発しています。

フロントエンドがlocalhost:3000で起動
バックエンドがlocakhost:8080で起動

APIへのアクセスはアプリが発行するアクセストークン（JWT）を使用して行われます。
アクセストークン自体は30分で有効期限が切れるのでCookieに保存されたリフレッシュトークンで都度アクセストークンを発行しながらアプリを操作するフローになっています。
このアプリに対してGoogleログインを実装したいです。
試したこと
omniauth-google-oauth2
omniauth-google-oauth2 というgemを使って実装を試みました。
しかしrailsをAPIモードで使用しない場合に提供されるcsrfトークンの認証部分でエラーになり（おそらく）SPAの場合このバックエンドで発行されるトークンをフロントエンドに自前で渡す必要があったため下記のエラーが発生して、認証画面にリダイレクトさせられなかった。
あとはrails API側からフロントエンドに対してリダイレクトのリクエストを投げるのもcorsの関係でエラーになるため、omniauth-google-oauth2でGoogle認証を実装するのは難しいと判断しました。
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken これと同じエラーが出ていた
そして、自分の場合は記事の内容通りにキャッシュの設定を変更したがエラー内容が変わらなかった。
追記
A（Next.js）, B(認可サーバ), C(rails API)とサーバがあるとする。
AからBにリクエストを投げるとCにリクエストがリダイレクトされます。その後Cがレスポンスを返すと最終的にレスポンスはAに届くからCookieとレスポンスを受け取れる気もする。これが出来ればこの方法がシンプルで一番良い。認証のページに遷移させられない...
追記2
上記でcsrfトークンの認証エラーになって断念したという話になっていましたが、こちらに関してはバックエンドが発行して リダイレクト先 として遷移させる予定のパスをフロントエンドで生成する事で対応しました。
おそらく rails apiで外部に対してredirect_toを使うと blocked by CORS policy: で処理が進まないためこれによってGoogleの認証ページ遷移していなかったと思われます。
そのためフロントエンドのGoogle認証ボタンの所にaタグでリンクを貼り、ユーザ認証ページに遷移して対応しました。
そのまま認証を進めるとバックエンドに認証したユーザ情報が届くのを確認出来ました。
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&response_type=code&client_id={ client_id }&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fauth%2Fgoogle_oauth2%2Fcallback

ただ問題が発生してます。
http://localhost:8080/auth/google_oauth2/callback?code=
このURLにアクセストークンとリフレッシュトークンが返ってきているのでフロントエンド(http://localhost:3000)に届かないです。
# ルーティング 
get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'api/v1/google_oauth2#create'

# コールバック先の api/v1/google_oauth2#create
  def create
    delete_session

    user_authed = User.from_google_oauth2(oauth_params)
    # ここのrenderで返すアクセストークンとリフレッシュトークンがhttp://localhost:8080/auth/google... に返ってきてしまうのでフロントエンドに渡らない...
    render status: :created, json: login_response_with_cookie(user_authed)
  end

何か良い方法はないでしょうか。
Auth.js（NextAuth.js）
次にフロントエンドで流行っているライブラリでAuth.jsというのがあると聞いてこちらを使用することを検討しました。
こちらはボタンがクリックされた際にGoogleの認証画面に遷移されて、ユーザのプロフィールデータを取得する所まで出来ました。
# サーバアクション
'use server'

import { signIn } from '@/auth'

export const createUserGoogle = async () => {
  await signIn('google', { redirectTo: '/' })
}

# クライアント側
<form action={createUserGoogle}>
  <button
    type='submit'
    className='w-full border font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center hover:opacity-70 sub-bg-color main-border-color'
  >
    <GoogleIcon className='w-5 h-5 mr-2 inline' />
    Sign Up With Google
  </button>
</form>

ただ問題点があります。
ログイン後は通常のユーザと同じようにアプリが発行するアクセストークンとリフレッシュトークンを渡したフローを行いたいです。
そのため認証後にコントローラにユーザが作成されるようにユーザ情報を飛ばす処理を追加しました。
それによってAPI側でユーザが作成されるところまでは出来ました。
しかし、アクセストークンとリフレッシュトークンを受け取ってクライアント側に渡す方法が分からず、こちらの実装方法も厳しいのではと考えています。
理由とてはsignIn() メソッドがNever型で何も返さないためです。なので受け取ったResponseを返す事が出来ません。
おそらく渡すにはサーバサイドで受け取ったアクセストークンをサーバのどこかに保存してクライアントで受け取るような操作が必要です。
Auth.jsが用意するセッションに保存するのが良さそう（できるなら）ですが、使い方として正しいか自信がないです。
そして、すでにセッションのフローを自前で用意した状態でAuth.jsを使うのもオーバーな気がします。
フロントエンドに認証の責務を置くのも微妙な感じです。
ただアクセストークンが渡せる方法があるならそれを元に再びAPIにリクエストを投げて、その際にリフレッシュトークンを発行してアプリのフローにする方法も仕方ないかなとも考えています。
# auth.ts
import { postGoogleOuth2 } from '@/lib/wrappedFeatch/requests/auth'
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import Google from 'next-auth/providers/google'
import { FetchError } from './lib/errors'

export const { handlers, signIn, signOut, auth } = NextAuth({
  providers: [Google],
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account }) {
      const data = {
        provider: account?.provider,
        name: user.name,
        email: user.email,
        image: user.image,
      }

      const response = await postGoogleOuth2(data)

      if (response instanceof FetchError) {
        // Return false to display a default error message
        return false
        // Or you can return a URL to redirect to:
        // return '/unauthorized'
      } else {
        return true
      }
    },
  },
})

# コントローラ側
class Api::V1::GoogleOauth2Controller < ApplicationController
  include LoginResponseConcern

  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid do |error|
    status_unprocessable_entity(error.message)
  end

  def create
    delete_session

    user_authed = User.from_google_oauth2(oauth_params)
    # ユーザを作成してアクセストークン(JWT)とリフレッシュトークン（cookie）を返す処理
    render status: :created, json: login_response_with_cookie(user_authed)
  end

  private

  def oauth_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:provider, :name, :email, :image)
  end
end


やりたいこと
可能であればバックエンドにoauth認証の責務を持たせてフロントエンドはAPIに対してリクエストを投げるだけにしたいです。
フロントエンドから自作のGoogleボタンクリック（リンクさえ作れば遷移させられると思ってる） → Google認証ページにユーザを遷移 → ユーザ操作による認証 → rails apiにプロフィール情報（メールアドレス）をcallbackさせてユーザ作成 → アクセストークンとリフレッシュトークンをクライアントに渡したい。（ここの方法が全然思いつかない...）
ここを行うにはNext.js側でAPIを立ててrails APIからコールバックさせるしかない気がする。
そしてNext.jsのサーバサイドで受け取ったアクセストークンとリフレッシュトークンをクライアントにどうにか渡す。
どうしてこんな壮大な流れになってしまうんだ。
このフローだとcallbackでAPIにpostリクエストが返るけど、その返却先をクライアントに出来るのか分からない。
かりにそのままレスポンスを返却してもGoogle側に行くだけな気がする。
なのでプロフィール情報を一旦フロントエンドで受け取って、その後にコントローラに対してname, email, imageを送信する方法も考えたのですが、これだと現状のコントローラ側の実装だとユーザ作成とログインをになっているので、リクエストに対してなんらかの認証をかけないとメールアドレスが分かるだけでアクセストークンとリフレッシュトークンが返るという危険な実装になってしまいます。
この辺り詳しい方お力を貸していただけないでしょうか。
どのような考えで実装を進めていけば良いか教えて頂けだけでも助かります。
実際皆さんだったらどのように実装を進めますでしょうか。
どのように実装すると綺麗に出来るのか教えて欲しいです。
調査等含め1週間ほど開発が進まない状態になって困っております。
よろしくお願いします。
足りない情報等あればすぐに追加します。
考えた方法
フロントエンドで認証を済ませて、アクセストークン（Googleが発行する）を貰う、それをRails APIに渡す、ユーザのプロフィールを取得、ユーザの取得・ユーザ作成してアクセストークン・リフレッシュトークンと共にフロントエンドに返す。
これが一番、綺麗に落ち着きそう。
